# Кольцевой список, используя контейнер list

Tags: c++, списки, двусвязный-список

Проблема вот в чём, мне необходимо создать двусвязный кольцевой список используя контейнер list. Двусвязный он по умолчанию, а вот кольцевая связь никак не удается, компилятор отвергает подобный вариант:

```
myList.front._Prevnode = myList.back;
myList.back._Nextnode = myList.front;
```

получаю соответсвенные ошибки:

```
left of .Prevnode must have class/struct/union
left of .Nextnode must have class/struct/union
```

помогите пожалуйста, обясните что я делаю не так, и как используя контейнер list организовать кольцевой список?

Возможно нужно использовать итератор?

Comment: Лучше этого не делать. Подобные [трюки](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992007/is-it-safe-to-use-stdlist-as-a-circular-list) содержат UB.

Comment: Нашёл ответ на английском языке http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882090/extend-stdlist-to-cylic-list

Answer (score 1):

В стандарте вообще не описаны никакие члены-указатели на следующий и предыдущий элементы, так что в самом лучшем случае у вас будет привязка к конкретной реализации.

Далее - вопрос: зачем? Чего вы хотите добиться? Ведь при этом вы, например, теряете возможность работы с итераторами - нет больше ни начала списка, ни его конца!

Как по мне - наиболее простой способ получения требуемой вам функциональности (какой??) - написать адаптер...

Comment: Я так подозреваю, что преподаватель подразумевал написание своего списка, а не std::list